# Why is it not possible to store DD-MM-YYYY format in date format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to convert date type information in the "YYYY-MM-DD" format to "DD-MM-YYYY" but I wanted to keep the date type, but I'm not able to tell you why? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
import moment

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2022-12-10", "2022-12-11", "2022-12-12"]})
df["Date"] = [moment.date(s).format('D-M-YYYY') for s in df["Date"]]

print(df)
print(df["Date"].dtypes)

         Date
0  10-12-2022
1  11-12-2022
2  12-12-2022
object
```

```
import pendulum as pdl

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2022-12-10", "2022-12-11", "2022-12-12"]})
df["Date"] = [pdl.from_format(s, 'YYYY-MM-DD', tz='America/Sao_Paulo').format('D-M-YYYY') for s in df["Date"]]

print(df)
print(df["Date"].dtypes)

 Date
0  10-12-2022
1  11-12-2022
2  12-12-2022
object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the format of the solutions you have tried, a correct way to do it (not the most efficient) is:

```
import datetime

df["Date"] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%m-%Y') for s in df["Date"]]
```

If you need more efficiency in the solution, the ideal would be to use vectorized operations, for example:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

Or in a single line:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Question is `Why is it not possible to store DD-MM-YYYY format in date format?` - answer is `because python not support it`. Cannot format `DD-MM-YYY` and dates or datetimes. Only strings like mentioned in question.